# Puedo ocultar un directorio de una url a traves del .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

Tengo una página web en un servidor dedicado. La página está hecha en `WordPress` y está ubicada dentro de la carpeta `public_html` en la carpeta `pagina1`.

Cuando entro a la página, en la `URL` me aparece el directorio donde se encuentra dicha página de esta forma:

`www.paginaweb.com/pagina1`

Sé que en la carpeta `pagina1` se encuentran todos los archivos de esa página pero, ¿es posible que la página se muestre sin que aparezca el subdirectorio `pagina1` en la `URL`? Una forma sería colocar todos los archivos de la página en la carpeta `public_html`, pero mi idea es tratar de mantener todo ordenado y por eso creé una carpeta para guardar los archivos de la página en esa carpeta.

He intentado con varios códigos que encontré en internet modificando el `.htaccess`, tanto el de `public_html` como el que está dentro de la carpeta `pagina1`, pero no he logrado que funcione. También intenté modificar el archivo `wp-config.php`.

¿Alguna idea?

Esto es lo que he probado:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?paginaweb.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pagina1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pagina1/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?paginaweb.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ pagina1/index.php [L]
```

También intenté con esto en el `wp-config.php`, pero no me carga la página:

```
define('WP_SITEURL','http://paginaweb.com');
define('WP_HOME','http://paginaweb.com');
define('RELOCATE',true);
```

Comment: ¿Tendrías que mantener el panel `wp-admin`, `wp-content` y `wp-includes`?

Comment: si tenes un wordpress en una carpeta y queres accederlo desde la raiz, primero le cambias el site url ( desde el admin o la DB ), luego copias el .htaccess y el index.php a la carpeta raíz, ajustas el require en este último y ya estarías ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Method_II_.28With_URL_change.29

Comment: @aloMalbarez que debo colocar en el require del index.php? la direccion donde se encuentra la pagina? es decir, pagina1 ?

Answer (score 0):

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Navegando por SE y SO, he encontrado el siguiente código:

```
RewriteBase \
RedirectMatch 301 ^/pagina1/$ /$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/pagina1/(?!wp-admin/|wp-content/|wp-includes/)(.*)$ /$1
```

Fuente: [enlace](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/163536)

**Importante**, el usuario indica que lo utiliza en el `.htaccess` de su subdirectorio, es decir, de tu directorio `prueba1`. Pruébalo ahí.

En el hilo se indica un problema similar al tuyo, es decir, se buscaba que un subdirectorio `WordPress` funcionase como si estuviera montado sobre el directorio root.

---

**PRIMERA RESPUESTA**

Prueba en el fichero `.htaccess` del directorio root algo como esto:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.paginaweb.com
RewriteRule ^pagina1/(.*)$ http://www.paginaweb.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hola smt, eso ya lo probe antes de hacer esta pregunta pero no funciona, lo hice tanto en el .htaaccess que se encuentra en la carpeta pública como en el .htaccess que está dentro del subdirectorio pagina1. Si es posible lo que quiero hacer? Xq he probado numeros cosas y nada que funciona.

Comment: Sí, sí que se puede, algo tiene que haber por ahí. Estaría bien que pusieras lo que ya has probado previamente para descartar.

Comment: Hola smt. acabo de editar mi pregunta con lo que he intentado hasta ahora. gracias de antemano por tu respuesta.

Comment: Si coloco el codigo que tu me pasaste carga el index de la pagina con los subdirectorios y todo en un html muy sencilo y si hago click en el subdirectorio pagina1 me abre la pagina pero colocando el subdirectorio en la url tal cual como lo tengo ahora. alguna otra idea?

Comment: @JulianProg echa un ojo a la actualización del hilo. Tal vez eso funcione.

Comment: @smt la respuesta del enlace tiene que ver con manejar los 404 luego de cambiar la url, es necesario primero el paso indicado en el [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Method_II_.28With_URL_change.29) ( o en la segunda respuesta del enlace)

Comment: @aloMalbarez también tengo un pequeño problema que no me carga las imágenes, me aparecen como enlaces rotos, si hago click en ella y luego a ver imagen, me abre en otro en lace con error 404 y dice not found, alguna idea de porque pueda estar pasando eso?

Answer (score 0):

En la configuración del servidor, donde le indicas el dominio, debe salir alguna opción para indicar la carpeta en la que se aloja y alli pones tudominio/carpeta1/

Prueba y nos dices.